# How to get file location for @PropertySource in Spring from Maven property

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have 2 properties files stored in resources folder: qa.properties and dev.properties.

I specified Maven property 'environment', this is the name of property file that should be loaded.

```
 <properties>
        <environment>qa</environment>
 </properties>
```

I want to load required properties according to the maven variable, but @PropertySource doesn't see maven variables. How to pass 'environment' property from Maven to the @PropertySource?

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:${environment}.properties")
public class Config {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public Environment getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't. Maven property is built-time. Spring is run-time. You need to make your build deploy a different file on a common name for Spring to see.

Comment: What you should look into is the [profile feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) that spring offers, this will allow you to instantiate beans conditionally based on active profiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this at build time using a `Maven` property. This approach forces you to build an artifact for every environment which is not a good practice.

A better approach is to build only one artifact and/or application to be deployed in any environment (qa, stage, load-test, prod, ....)

One way is to name your property files `application-test.properties`, `application-xxxxx.properties` and run you application as:

`java -Dspring.profiles.active=qa myapp.jar`

No need for the `Config` class you described earlier if you follow this approach.

This should get you started. Notice you would have to include property files for different environments but this could also be worked out. Take a look at the [12 factor-app](https://12factor.net/).

Comment: Currently I implemented logic using spring profile-specific properties. It works fine when I specify profile using this command: -Dspring.profiles.active=qa. But when profile is not specified default profile will be used. How I can specify the default profile to not write -Dspring.profiles.active=qa every time?

Comment: You could add `spring.profiles.active=qa` to `bootstrap.properties`

Comment: I added spring.profiles.active=@environment@ to application.properties and now my application run with profile specified in the Maven 'environment' property.

Comment: That would be the default environment coming from Maven, passing the value from Maven is debatable. but if you want to run the same app in another environment you could use -Dspring.profiles.active=stage without the need to compile and produce another binary a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use profile-specific properties like `application-qa.properties` for this purpose and activate it in application.properties with `spring.profiles.active=qa` here more https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you have to specify your *environment* property as *System* property. *Maven Surefire Plugin* can help you with that:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <environment>QA</environment>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```